# When I create a task and then cancel it, it status says cancelled, but comparing it to TaskStatus.Canceled returns false

Tags: c#, task

I dont understand why, iscancelled is false, when task.Status = cancelled

```
        var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
        task = Task.Run(() => GetValueToPrint(), cancellation.Token);
        cancellation.Cancel();

        bool iscancelled = task.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled;
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: What is task.Status in that case?

Comment: its cancelled, but task.Status is a method which comes from task class.

Comment: I think you need to give it more time https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Comparing it to canceled is false, therefore the status is not cancelled. What is the status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`task.Status` will only equal `Canceled` if one of two conditions are met.

1. the cancelation token is already in the canceled state before the `Task.Run` call was made.
2. The code that was run inside the `Task.Run` threw a [OperationCanceledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) and the token that was passed in to the constructor of the exception was the same token (or a [linked token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642252(v=vs.110).aspx) to the same token) that was passed in to the `Task.Run`

You do not have either of those situations so either your task likely in the `Running` or `RanToCompletion` state at the point of your check.

If you want to be able to cancel `GetValueToPrint()` after it has been started you must pass the same token in to it as a parameter then throughout the method you need to call [`token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested(v=vs.110).aspx) on the passed in token at spots that would be possible to cancel. Doing this will cause you to fall under #2 in the two options I listed above.

```
private string GetValueToPrint(CancellationToken token)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Loop");
       token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
   }
   return "42";
}

private void Example()
{
    var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    task = Task.Run(() => GetValueToPrint(cancellation.Token), cancellation.Token);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    cancellation.Cancel();

    bool iscancelled = task.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled;
    Console.WriteLine(iscancelled);
}
```

You will see "Loop" printed 4-6 times (its a bit of a race condition) then `iscancelled` will be true;